# Add TypeScript support to vue.global.prod.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vuejs3

Due to our setup, we use the `vue.global.prod.js` build of Vue and access Vue methods globally such as `const app = window.Vue.createApp` and `window.Vue.ref(false)`. I'm wondering if it's possible to add support via our `index.d.ts` file so all the `window.Vue` methods are recognised by TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue does not provide its types as a stand-alone package ([@types/vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vue) has been deprecated a long time ago). But you can import its typings inside a declaration file and assign them to the global `Window` interface:

Place this code inside a `vue-shim.d.ts`, in `src` folder <sup>***1, 2***</sup>:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
declare global {
    interface Window { Vue: typeof Vue }
}
```

Now you can use something along these lines in any TypeScript fragment:

```
const { createApp, ref } = window.Vue

// use `createApp` and `ref`, they're typed
```

---

<sup>***1***</sup> - for this to work you need `vue` installed in the project, but only for its types (TypeScript needs to read them from somewhere, right?). But you won't be importing `vue` anywhere (other than the above declaration file, which is not included in runtime code).
<sup>***2***</sup> - `Vue` will be typed in your project according to the installed version (in `package.json`), which might end up being different than the one imported from the cdn. They need to be kept in sync, going forward.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `import * as Vue from 'vue'`? (I don't remember)

Comment: @Dimava I test all my answers before posting. If I don't I specify I haven't.